# Custom AuthorizeAttribute on WebApi OData EntitySetController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, authorize-attribute

I created custom authorize attribute to handle my custom permissions on WebAPI odata controller inherited from EntitySetController, here is the code for my attribute

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RequirePermissionsAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public Permissions[] Permissions { get; set; }


    public RequirePermissionsAttribute()
    { }

    public RequirePermissionsAttribute(params Permissions[] permissions)
    {
        this.Permissions = permissions;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
       // Custom  authorization logic
    }
```

Now I try to add this attribute on Get() method, it get invoked

```cs
public class ItemsController : EntitySetController<Item, Guid>
{
   [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 5)]
   [RequirePermissionsAttribute(Permissions.ViewAll)]
   public override IQueryable<Item> Get()
   {
     //Code go here
   }
}
```

But when I add the same attribute on CreateEntity() it never get invoked

```cs
[RequirePermissionsAttribute(Permissions.Add)]
protected override Item CreateEntity(Item item)
{
  // Create item
}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use your attribute as RequirePermissions without the tailed "Attribute" word, So change your code to be like this

`[RequirePermissions(Permissions.Add)]
protected override Item CreateEntity(Item item)
{
  // Create item
}`

Answer (score 0):

Islam

From the WebAPI source codes, the internal virtual function `CreateEntity()` is called in POST request. Here's the source codes in `EntitySetController`:

```
public virtual HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] TEntity entity)
{
    TEntity createdEntity = CreateEntity(entity);
    TKey entityKey = GetKey(entity);
    return EntitySetControllerHelpers.PostResponse(this, createdEntity, entityKey);
}
```

I use your sample codes and send a POST request, the `CreateEntity()` can be invoked as:

```
POST ~/odata/Items

Content-type: application/json

{"Id":"9daf653f-212c-42e3-80a4-4778e445c092"}
```

[image]

However, if you want to get the correct response, you should override `GetKey()` because `GetKey()` is called after `CreateEntity()` in the `Post()` method. The same information is also mentioned in the remarks of `CreateEntity()` as below:

[image]

**Sample Test**

I create the following two functions in `ItemsController`:

```
protected override Guid GetKey(Item entity)
{
    return entity.Id;
}

[RequirePermissionsAttribute(Permissions.Add)]
protected override Item CreateEntity(Item item)
{
    // Create item
    return item;
}
```

And send the same POST request mentioned above, I can get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache
.....
Content-Length: 124

{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:47794/odata/$metadata#Items/@Element","Id":"9daf653f-212c-42e3-80a4-4778e445c092"
}
```

Hope it can help you. Thanks.